# After insert not working

Tags: sql-server-2012, triggers

all `id` columns has auto_increment

In my trigger:

```
    ALTER trigger [dbo].[mytrig] 
on [dbo].[requests]
after INSERT, UPDATE 
as
begin 
declare @MyId1 int
set @MyId1 = (select Id from inserted)
declare @MyId2 int
declare @MyId3 int 
if (select column1 from inserted) = 1
begin
insert into [dbo].[contracts] select column1,column2,column3 .... from inserted
set @MyId2 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
insert into [dbo].[History] select column1,column2,column3 ....  from inserted
set @MyId3 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
insert into [dbo].[contracts_depts](Id_Contract ,column5)  select @MyId2,column6 from request_depts where Id_request=@MyId1
insert into [dbo].[History_depts]  (Id_InHistory,column5)  select @MyId3,column6 from request_depts where Id_request=@MyId1
end
end
```

`@MyId1` returns value only after update but not after insert. Do I have to use `scope_identity()` or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is: you're assuming the triggers is called once per row - that is **NOT** the case!

The trigger is called **once per statement**, and if your statement affects multiple rows, the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain **multiple rows** - so your statement here

```
set @MyId1 = (select Id from inserted)
```

really isn't going to work - it will select one arbitrary row (out of however many there are).

You'll need to rewrite your trigger to take this fact into account! Assume that `Inserted` contains 100 rows - how do you want to deal with that? What are you trying to achieve? Triggers don't *return values* - they will record into an audit table, or update other rows, or something like that ....

Comment: in my case the user can insert only one row at a time . i only need to get the id of the record he just inserted so i can use it to update other tables. when user edits the record the id is "visible" but after inser not...

Comment: @Theodore: adding just inserted `ID` to an audit table in a trigger works just fine for me.... you'll have to show us more - table structures, your **entire** code for the trigger - otherwise we don't be able to help